# Android privacy policy into app or just on website?

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

I've made a app privacy policy on the website, but do I need to create one in the app also ?

From Google developer support documents:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311

> Post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console
> and within the app itself.

Do I need to create a page in the app dedicated for the privacy policy or should I make only a reference/link in the app to the policy page on the website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a privacy policy in the app and on the website, just to be sure. The app was accepted from the first try.

Even if google doesn't punish developers for not publishing privacy policies within the apps, they clearly state that you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a reference/link in the app to the policy page on the website. Google will not ban your application for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the policy directly in the app but you may need a public-accessible link if you'd like to add it on the app store listing as well:

[image: Google Play Privacy Policy URL]

Screenshot from Google Play Store Store Listing page:

[image]

Comment: I know about that one. But didn't know if I should also create a policy page in the app, because (from google docs): "Post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console and within the app itself."

Answer (score 0):

As @cat15ets said, I want to reconfirm that Google/Android did not removed the App from the PlayStore and even did not send any notice or warning for doing that.

I further assumed, that should be an OPTIONAL requirement.